# How to update icon file sizes in an air app?

Tags: ios, air

I'm using FlashBuilder 4.6 with SDK 4.0 to update a couple of apps I haven't touched for a couple of years.

The requirements for iOs launch icon sizes, depending on whether it is iOs 7 or earlier,  have changed, as detailed [here](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/App-RelatedResources/App-RelatedResources.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH6-SW1).

Here is what I had before:

```
<icon>
    <image16x16>assets/icon_16x16.png</image16x16>
    <image32x32>assets/icon_32x32.png</image32x32>
    <image36x36>assets/icon_36x36.png</image36x36>
    <image48x48>assets/icon_48x48.png</image48x48>
    <image57x57>assets/icon_57x57.png</image57x57>
    <image72x72>assets/icon_72x72.png</image72x72>
    <image114x114>assets/icon_114x114.png</image114x114>
    <image128x128>assets/icon_128x128.png</image128x128>
    <image1024x1024>assets/icon_1024x1024.png</image1024x1024>
</icon>
```

How do I include the new file sizes? Is it as simple as adding the new ones in the correct dimensions, like this:

```
<icon>
    <image60x60>assets/icon_60x60.png</image60x60>
    <image120x120>assets/icon_120x120.png</image120x120>
    <image76x76>assets/icon_76x76.png</image76x76>
    <image152x152>assets/icon_152x152.png</image152x152>
            etc.
</icon>
```

Also, do I have to worry about naming the double-sized icons using the "@2x"convention? If so, how should I name them in the above examples?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is add the new image sizes to the `icon` array, so it is as simple as it seems. You do not need to use the '@2x' naming scheme for anything except the Launch images.

Make sure you are running the latest version of AIR, though. You won't be able to submit to the iTunes Store with anything less than 4.0 (AIR is currently on version 13.0) anymore. The icons you are trying to add weren't added to AIR until 3.9, anyway.

Comment: Thanks. I wrote 'AIR 4.6' but meant 'Flash Builder 4.6'-- since corrected. And I was using an old AIR version -- have just now updated.